# Script to get Group Member, group starting with "ADM*"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have a requirement to generate a CSV report to get group members. However, I there are many child domains which contains groups starting with *ADM*.

I need report in the following format:

```
GroupName   User    Company     LasLogon    CN
ADM_AM  UserOne     CP1
```

I've found one script on internet:

```bsh
Get-ADGroup -Server dc1.chd1.pd.local -Filter 'Name -like "ADM*"' |
     ForEach-Object{
          $hash=@{GroupName=$_.Name;Member=''}
          $_ | Get-ADGroupMember -ea 0 -recurs |
               ForEach-Object{
                    $hash.Member=$_.Name
                    New-Object psObject -Property $hash
               }
          } |
     sort groupname,member
```

This script only gives me GroupName and UserName but not other information.

How can I generate this report?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "ADM_AM, UserOne, CP1" is, but i got this much for you. I'm still new to powershell so forgive me if this is a lot of code =)

```
$array = @()
Foreach ($group in (Get-ADGroup -Server dc1.chd1.pd.local -Filter 'Name -like "ADM*"'))
{
    $hash=@{Username ='';GroupName=$group.Name;Company='';LastLogon='';CN=''}
    $members = $hash.GroupName | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Foreach($member in $members)
    {
        $properties = $member.SamAccountName | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName, Company, lastLogon, CN
        $hash.Username = $properties.SamAccountName
        $hash.Company = $properties.Company
        $hash.LastLogon = $properties.lastLogon
        $hash.CN = $properties.CN
        $obj = New-Object psObject -Property $hash
        $array += $obj      
    }   
}   
$array | Export-Csv C:\ -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello HiTech, I am getting following error: Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "@{samaccountname=ADM_GR_De}" value of type "Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup" to 
type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup".
At line:6 char:33
+     $members = get-adgroupmember <<<<  $group | select samaccountName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At line:9 char:31
+         $memprops = get-aduser <<<<  $member -properties company
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At line:8 char:58
+         $properties = $member.SamAccountName | Get-ADUser <<<<  -Properties SamAccountName, Company, lastLogon, CN
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, Im sure you can shorten it.  You shoud specify a searchbase.  Once you have the members samaccountname, you can use Get-ADUser to get whatever fields you want.

```
$GrpArr = @()
$Groups = get-adgroup -filter {name -like "adm*"} -searchbase "ou=Groups,dc=all,dc=ca" | select samaccountname
foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    $GrpArr += $group
    $members = get-adgroupmember $group | select samaccountName
    foreach ($member in $members)
    {
        $memprops = get-aduser $member -properties company
        $comp = $memprops.company
        $grpArr += "$member,$comp"
    }
}
$grpArr | export-csv c:\temp\Groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Bill, I am getting error: Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "@{samaccountname=ADM_GR_De}" value of type "Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup" to 
type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup".
At line:6 char:33
+     $members = get-adgroupmember <<<<  $group | select samaccountName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At line:9 char:31
+         $memprops = get-aduser <<<<  $member -properties company
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser